# babel не компилирует

Tags: javascript, babel

настройки package.json

```
{
   "name": "testwebpack",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "description": "",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
       "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
       "dev": "webpack"
   },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "devDependencies": {
       "@babel/cli": "^7.8.3",
       "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
       "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
       "webpack": "^4.41.5",
       "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
   },
   "dependencies": {
       "@babel/polyfill": "^7.8.3"
   }
}
```

настройки webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: { main: './js/index.js' },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    watch: true,

    devtool: "source-map"

}
```

настройки babel.config.json

```
const presets = [
    [
        "@babel/env",
        {
            targets: {
                edge: "17",
                firefox: "60",
                chrome: "67",
                safari: "11.1",
                ie: "11",
            },
            useBuiltIns: "usage"
        },
    ],
];

module.exports = { presets };
```

npx babel parts --out-dir parts выдает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при этом в файлах let на var не меняются

Comment: Ну, видимо, потому что все указанные в `targets` браузеры понимают `let`, babel не видит смысла заменять его на `var`

Comment: @DmitryKozlov проверил через https://caniuse.com/#search=let, точно было сказано